# Honestly, where has Raven.server.exe gone?

Tags: ravendb

The subject says it all - I updated my RavenDB in Nuget, and Raven.server.exe has done a runner... where is it??

Comment: I think the nugets for raven have been updated recently. check the contents? I tend to download the server from the website

Comment: Woohoo, its appeared again, but you do need to use the pre-release "Install-Package RavenDB.Server -Pre"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

http://nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Server

Answer (score 1):

Adam, try [watching this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEszs1Y-Jeo) which explains what version to use and where.

VS projects should either be using the [RavenDb.Client](http://nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Client/) or [RavenDb.Embedded](http://nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Embedded/) .. and just download the RavenDb Server separately. (again, refer to that video for why/how/etc)